# Can you explain this to me

Tags: meaning, grammar

Can you explain this sentence to me.

> Nothing beats the feeling of having done more in twenty-four hours than what the day expected you to!

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: There is nothing in this sentence that needs an explanation so far as English language and usage is concerned.

Comment: I want his meaning

Comment: What the author is trying to say

Comment: What part of the sentence are you having trouble with? *Nothing beats the feeling*, *the day*, or *expected you to*? Or something else?

Comment: Nothing beats the feeling

Comment: Include what you found in a dictionary.  Was there no definition given that fits this quote?

Comment: Do not delete and repost closed questions. Edit and fix them. Continuing to do this may cause the system to block you from asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

The narrator is feeling good about essentially over-achieving on what the expected output from their efforts were expected to be over the day.

Here, the 'day' is somewhat anthropomorphised and lays an expectation on what is achievable. When the narrator has done more than that in the 'actual' day (24 hours) there is a sense of achievement and fulfillment.

Comment: Thanks i finally understood..in fact i was having trouble with nothing beats the feeling which means this feeling of having done more in 24 hours than what the day expected you to is the best